# convergence/divergence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n^3+\tanh(n)}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n^3+\tanh(n)}}$$

$-1<\tanh(n)<1$ so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n^3+\tanh(n)}}$ but it does not seems to help

Comment: for big $n$ the terms of ur sum go roughly like
$$
\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}\approx\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3}}=n^{-1/2}
$$

and therefor the series diverges (the $\log(n)$ terms are subleading)

Comment: @tired but $n^{-1/2}$ is bigger than the expression

Comment: the point is that they are asymptotically equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost done, show that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+\ln n}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}$ diverges by the comparison test, using $$ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}n^{-1/2}=\frac{n}{\sqrt{2n^3}} \leqslant \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3+1}} \leqslant \frac{n+\ln n}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}.\qquad$$

Comment: why can I say that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot n^{-1/2}$ diverge? I understand for  $n^{-1/2}$ but what about $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: @gbox $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}ca_n=c\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}a_n$.

Comment: @gbox You habe already been explained this mistake of yours, no? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705510/convergence-divergence-sum-n-1-infty-frac2n-13n2-cdot-n-frac4/1705513#comment3480951_1705513